# Using a pointer reference to a foreign-key related model in Gorm (golang)

Tags: go, pointers, struct, foreign-keys, go-gorm

Suppose you have database models as follows:

```
package storage

type Country struct {
    ID   string `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Code string `json:"code"`
}

type City struct {
    ID           string   `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Code         *string  `json:"code"`
    CountryId    string   `json:"country_id"`
    Country      *Country `json:"country" gorm:"references:ID"`
    IATA         *string  `json:"iata"`
    Latitude     *string  `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude    *string  `json:"longitude"`
}
```

The city should have a pointer to a Country model to make it easier to understand whether Country has been joined (in sql) or not (e.g. `if city.Country == nil {panic("for whatever reason")}` )

**The problem appears when I try to get the list of all cities:**

```
package example

var cities []storage.City 
tx.Joins("Country").Find(&cities)
```

Here, all the cities have been fetched from DB nicely, but the **countries became the same in all the cities.**

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
[
{
 ID:51e415ab-4301-4268-9345-deed6b1d72f6 
 Name:Bergen 
 Code:0xc0004d6ec0 
 CountryId:0bd3890c-b6b7-4b27-8071-55c8f64562bb 
 Country:{
    ID:0bd3890c-b6b7-4b27-8071-55c8f64562bb 
    Name:Norwegen 
    Code:NO
   } 
 SkyScannerId:0xc0004d6ee0 
 IATA:0xc0004d6ef0 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6f00 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6f10
},
 
{
 ID:2468c7f0-0275-4bff-8b7e-4e87bfa63604 
 Name:Banská Bystrica 
 Code:0xc0004d6bc0 
 CountryId:00ba76d3-9591-4d45-a39d-f554375d790f 
 Country: {
    ID:00ba76d3-9591-4d45-a39d-f554375d790f 
    Name:Slovakei 
    Code:SK
   } 
 SkyScannerId:<nil> 
 IATA:<nil> 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6c00 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6c10
}, 

{
 ID:75501988-3c80-4ef9-8081-73d20cbcc29b 
 Name:Prag 
 Code:0xc0004d6a60 
 CountryId:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
 Country:{
    ID:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
    Name:Tschechien 
    Code:CZ
  } 
 SkyScannerId:0xc0004d6a90 
 IATA:0xc0004d6aa0 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6ac0 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6ad0
}
] 



ACTUAL OUTPUT:

[
{
 ID:51e415ab-4301-4268-9345-deed6b1d72f6 
 Name:Bergen 
 Code:0xc0004d6ec0 
 CountryId:0bd3890c-b6b7-4b27-8071-55c8f64562bb 
 Country:{
    ID:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
    Name:Tschechien 
    Code:CZ
  }
 SkyScannerId:0xc0004d6ee0 
 IATA:0xc0004d6ef0 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6f00 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6f10
},
 
{
 ID:2468c7f0-0275-4bff-8b7e-4e87bfa63604 
 Name:Banská Bystrica 
 Code:0xc0004d6bc0 
 CountryId:00ba76d3-9591-4d45-a39d-f554375d790f 
 Country:{
    ID:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
    Name:Tschechien 
    Code:CZ
  }
 SkyScannerId:<nil> 
 IATA:<nil> 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6c00 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6c10
}, 

{
 ID:75501988-3c80-4ef9-8081-73d20cbcc29b 
 Name:Prag 
 Code:0xc0004d6a60 
 CountryId:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
 Country:{
    ID:f4e819b2-5c1a-43f9-bfa1-fe56b6ee173e 
    Name:Tschechien 
    Code:CZ
  } 
 SkyScannerId:0xc0004d6a90 
 IATA:0xc0004d6aa0 
 Latitude:0xc0004d6ac0 
 Longitude:0xc0004d6ad0
}
]
```

Please pay attention to **Country field of the outputs**. In the ACTUAL OUTPUT all the cities have the same country. I think this has something to do with the pointer.
I **got** EXPECTED OUTPUT when I **removed** **the** **pointer** from Country (so `*Country` became `Country` without `*`). But I would like to get the same output with the pointer (`*Country`).
Also, please do not pay attention to the values printed out in other fields. My main focus is the Country field.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

P.S. I know that i can survive without using the pointers too in the Country field, but I just want to know if there are any possibilities to do that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy Is it clearer now ? Thx

Comment: Please ask 1 question. Either about unexpected results or being stuck in "your overall goal", not both, and clearly 1st you should ask about the former to clear up misconceptions, and buggy code is not helpful for the latter. Why shouldn't you get that result?--"say what you expected & why, justified by documentation". Also "cut & paste & runnable code". Also minimal. Also what is the result before the find? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that this is the behavior with `gorm-v1.23.6`.  Switching back to `gorm-v1.23.5` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put countryId as a pointer too.

Like this

```
 CountryId    *string   `json:"country_id"`
```

Actually I tried to replicate the error with you code example, but it's working well.

Comment: Could you try it with v1.23.6 please. I think with that version you will get the error I got. Thx.